# AngularJS - Passing Values To Service On Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple ng-click, which at present, is passing a $index value from an ng-repeat via ng-init.

What i would like to know is how can i pass another defined value into my ng-click?

**Current HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="values in Categories" id="history-{{$index}}" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
      {{ values.Name }}, {{ values.Amount }}
</div>
<div>
    <div class="left" ng-click="scrollLeft(sectionIndex)"></div>
    <div class="right" ng-click="scrollRight(sectionIndex)"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.scrollLeft = scrollLeftRight.moveLeft;
$scope.scrollRight = scrollLeftRight.moveRight;


app.factory('scrollLeftRight', function () {
return {
  moveLeft: function (sectionIndex) {
    var scrollViewport_width = $(window).width();
    var pixelsToMove = 0;
    $('#history-' + sectionIndex).scrollLeft(pixelsToMove - 100);
    pixelsToMove = pixelsToMove - 100;
    if (pixelsToMove <= 0) {
      pixelsToMove = 0;  // reset
    } else {
      pixelsToMove = pixelsToMove;
    }
  },
  moveRight: function (sectionIndex) {
    var scrollViewport_width = $(window).width();
    var pixelsToMove = 0;
    $('#history-' + sectionIndex).scrollLeft(pixelsToMove + 100);
    pixelsToMove = pixelsToMove + 100;
    if (pixelsToMove >= scrollViewport_width) {
      pixelsToMove = scrollViewport_width;
    } else {
      pixelsToMove = pixelsToMove;
    }
  }
};
});
```

What i would like to know, is how can i pass another value in my ng-init (if possible), so something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="values in Categories" id="history-{{$index}}" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index, tableID='history'">
```

So that my second parameter tableID, can be passed into my function:

```
 moveRight: function (sectionIndex, tableID) {
```

And so that i no longer have to directly outline my id via:

```
$('#history-' + sectionIndex).scrollLeft(pixelsToMove - 100);
```

But instead:

```
$(tableID + sectionIndex).scrollLeft(pixelsToMove - 100);
```

Comment: Literally, `ng-init="sectionIndex = $index; tableID='history'"` (semicolon instead of comma) will help you, but your approach in Angular is far away from officially recommended. You should better create directive instead of factory for DOM manipulation. Checkout https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial for start if you want. It describes varity techniques and patterns used in AngularJS.

Comment: @dubadub - Thanks for the post, i was thinking of a directive initially.. But as i am moving an element to the left or right via scrollLeft, i thought a factory would be more fitting. What would a directive look like in the above scenario?

Comment: @dubadub - ive placed in ng-init="sectionIndex = $index; tableID='history'" and wihtin my moveRight: function i have placed a console.log("tableId = " + tableId);.. I see Undefined in my console

Comment: @dubadub - ignore my second post, i had a typo... If you could explain how to get in a directive, that would be very helpful

Comment: could you describe more details about your task? what do you have as container, better create fiddle (you can start with that http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4193/).

Comment: @dubadub - As you've answered the question in the post, ive created a new question here with a plunker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180020/angularjs-converting-incorrect-use-of-service-to-directive

Answer (score 1):

There are Some ways to do this : I know 2 of them :p

1-  **Dummy way** you can add A data-yourVariable into your Tag like this :

```
   <div ng-repeat="values in Categories" id="history-{{$index}}" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index" data-table="history">
```

And in your ng-click you can do like this :

```
        ng-click(sectionIndex,this.parent().data('table'));
```

2- **Simple** way : you can pass an object in your ng-init like this :

```
      ng-init="{sectionIndex: $index, tableID:'history}"
```

**NOTE**: You must use(:) instead of (=) in your ng-init because you want to use it as an object

So in your ng-click :

```
        ng-click(sectionIndex,tableID);
```

Hope that helps